# SQL: what kind of relation (1:1, 1:m, m:m,...) there is between this two tables?

Tags: sql, relationship

what kind of relation (1:1, 1:m, m:m, whatever) there is between this two tables?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `price` float default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_product_i18n` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `culture` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`,`culture`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `my_product_i18n`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `my_product_i18n_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `my_product` (`id`);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is 1:m you can have several different `culture` in `my_product_i18n connected` for each `id`.

**Edit:**
It is `PRIMARY KEY  ('id','culture')` in conjunction with the constraint that tells that you can have many `my_product_i18n`.

Answer (score 2):

1 to "maybe" - there's no guarantee that there will be a row in my_product_i18n, and the composite primary key of id and culture mean that you could have multiple rows for a given id, provided that those rows are of different cultures.

Answer (score 2):

This is a 1:M relationship. One row in `my_product` can have 0, 1, or more rows in `my_product_i18n` based off of the `culture` column.